# Need to create variable with multiple checkbox selected values of igCombo

Tags: javascript, jquery, infragistics, ignite-ui, igcombo

```
var selectedoptions = $("#spanid").igCombo("option","multiSelection")
```

Variable selectedoptions has an igCombo data structure but I need this variable to have string values of the checkbox users select. I am not able to get the correct values. any help?

Ignite UI is the library in case if anyone is wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `multiSelection` option will give you the configuration object for the multiple selection in the `igCombo`. In order to extract the selected items you need to use the `selectedItems` API method.

```
var items = $(".selector").igCombo("selectedItems");
var firstItemData = items[0].data;
var $firstItemLi = items[0].element;
```

https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2017.2/ui.igcombo#methods:selectedItems